# How to fix: If value is true count outcome with other different if statement outcomes?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I got multiple if statements, they check the cells column by column if there is a value "Yes" or "Mediocre". When "Yes" add +1 to the outcome if "Mediocre" add +0.5.

So my problem is as follows: When my code needs to check the next column it needs to do the same but then add +1 or +0.5 to the previous outcome on the same line in the same cell.

This needs to happen on every line.

Eventually when it checked the whole line, the outcome needs to be a percentage: count yes and mediocre then devide by 9 and multiple by 100.

I got an image how it should be below:

[Example how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoWEi.png)

I got the code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D2:L4"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        'If you add (an)other row(s) edit this code above
        Call DeleteP2P4
        'If you add (an)other row(s) edit this code above
        Call SampleMacro
    End If

End Sub

Sub DeleteP2P4()
    Range("P2:P4").Select
    'If you add (an)other row(s) edit this code above
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub

Sub SampleMacro()

    ' Get the last row
    Dim startRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    startRow = 2
    lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   For i = startRow To lastRow

    ' If there's Yes/Mediocre in D column, then append next number
    If Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
        Sheet1.Range("P" & i).Value = "+1"
    ElseIf Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value = "Mediocre" Then
        Sheet1.Range("P" & i).Value = "+0.5"
    End If

    ' If there's Yes/Mediocre in E column, then append next number
    If Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
        Sheet1.Range("P" & i).Value = "+1"
    ElseIf Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Value = "Mediocre" Then
        Sheet1.Range("P" & i).Value = "+0.5"
    End If

'It continious here with the rest of the If statements

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You are setting the value wrong, it should be similar to `Sheet1.Range("P" & i).Value = Sheet1.Range("P" & i).Value + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Brownish Monster, Change your

`Sheet1.Range("P" & i).Value = "+1"`

to

`Sheet1.Range("P" & i).Value = val(Sheet1.Range("P" & i).Value) + 1`

and similarly for Mediocre

`Sheet1.Range("P" & i).Value = val(Sheet1.Range("P" & i).Value) + 0.5`